# How can I get access or overridden the = operator in Swift?

Tags: swift

There is possibility in Swift for defining new custom operators like `infix operator **` but I do not want define a new operator, I want get access to the function or logic of `=` in Swift.

Here is what I am think about `=` operator, this code is just for show case and it does not work.

```
infix operator =
func =<T>(rhs: T) {
    // My custom code is here:
    print("rhs=",rhs)
    self = rhs
}
```

So how can I get access or even overridden `=` operator in Swift?

Comment: If you *code* do this, what would you like to use it for?

Comment: I am very interested to know how apple could define `=` operator in first place? because there is no `=` operator in first place, so how it is working?

Comment: Overloadable operators are the exception, not the rule. Usually it goes like this: the tokenizer will split up your source code into token. The parser will build an AST out of them. There might be a node in your AST called "operator_equals". When the compiler compiles that AST, it will eventually run into that node, and it will emit some instructions for it which performs the behaviour of `==` (which is hard-coded into the compiler). When operator overloading is involved (e.g. for `+`, there's an extra step: the compiler will see if you specify your own behaviour for `+` for those types

Comment: `==` just doesn't have that same "look through the user's code to see if they implemented an overload for these types" step. The compiler skips right to "i'll use this intrinsic definition I have built in".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **not** override the assignment operator (=), from the Swift Programming Language book

> NOTE
> It isn’t possible to overload the default assignment operator (=). Only the compound assignment operators can be overloaded. Similarly, the ternary conditional operator (a ? b : c) can’t be overloaded.

Quote from [this chapter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID42)

Answer (score 0):

You want to override `=`, the assignment operator, not `==`, the equality operator?

I don't think the assignment operator can be overridden.

However, You can define custom setters for any instance variable. That has the same effect as overriding the assignment operator. Consider this code:

```
class Foo {
    init(bar: Int) {
        self._bar = bar
    }
    public var bar: Int? {
        get {
            return _bar
        }
        set {
            // You can put any code you want in the setter.
            print("Setting bar to \(newValue)")
            _bar = newValue
        }
    }
    private var _bar: Int? = nil
}

var aFoo = Foo(bar: 1)

aFoo.bar = 12
print("aFoo.bar = \(aFoo.bar)")
```

That logs

> Setting bar to 12
>
> aFoo.bar = 12

To the console.

### Edit:

Consider this version of the code then:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Int {
    // Helper computed property to convert an `Optional<Int>` to a `String`.
    var intString: String {
        return self.map  { String($0) } ?? "nil"
    }
}

class Foo {
    init() {
    }
    init(bar: Int?) {
        self._bar = bar
    }
    public var bar: Int? {
        get {
            return _bar
        }
        // MARK: - This setter is the closest you can get to overriding the assignment operator.
        set {
            print("Setting bar to \(newValue.intString)")
            _bar = newValue
        }
        // MARK: -
    }
    private var _bar: Int?
}
var aFoo = Foo()
print("aFoo.bar = \(aFoo.bar.intString)")
aFoo.bar = 12
print("aFoo.bar = \(aFoo.bar.intString)")
```

That outputs:

> aFoo.bar = nil 
> Setting bar to 12 
> aFoo.bar = 12

(You can have an init for the Foo class that doesn't take any parameters, but then it needs to assign some value to the object's properties. I made the bar property Optional so it could default to nil.)

Comment: You got very close for my goal but I was looking for `aFoo = Foo(bar: 12)` not updating bar property.

Comment: Ok, I added an initializer that does not take any parameters (and changed `bar` to an `Optional` so it can default to `nil`.

Comment: You can have the body of your custom setter do whatever you want. If you don't assign a new value to the backing variable then the assignment operator won't change  anything. (But that sounds like a bad idea. A given expression should do what seems "natural" for that expression. We all expect the assignment operator to assign a new value to the property.)

Answer (score -2):

You cannot overload the = operator

Theres a complete article here: [Operator overloading/custom operators](https://digitalbunker.dev/operator-overloading-custom-operators-in-swift/)

To save your time :)

**Limitations Of Operator Overloading
There are a few additional caveats to mention.**

While ternary operator types (e.g. var userStatus = user.age >  18 ? .approved : .rejected) also exist in Swift, the language does not currently allow for overloading their operation.

**This same restriction applies to the default assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operator ( += ).**

Otherwise, all operators that begin with /, =, -, +, !, *, %, <, >, &, |, ^, ?, or ~, or are one of the Unicode characters specified here are fair game.

Comment: "This same restriction applies to the [...] compound assignment operator ( += )." This is just simply false. You *can* overload compound assignment operators, [as shown in the Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID44).